# facebook page info using Graph Api 2.2

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api-v2.2, graph-api-explorer

I have unique ID of 1000 facebook pages inside a google spreadsheet . I want to crawl all the pages to get their info (Likes, email etc) what should i do? Also i cannot run the search query in my browser and where to run a script. Plz be as detailed as possible. Thank u :)

I tried to make a python script for this but it works for 1st entry only.

```
import urllib as url2
import json


f=open('ids.txt')
for i in f:
        url="http://graph.facebook.com/"+str(int(i))+"?fields=likes"
        data = url2.urlopen(url).read()
        print data
        data2=json.loads(data)
        print "number of likes on page with id "+str(data2["id"])+" has "+str(data2["likes"])+" likes !"

f.close()
```

The ids.txt file contains id of facebook pages.

```
1 493343230696447
2 1767379894975
3 122116091270024
4 545044065615713
```

Comment: Does the file contain two columns, one for index and one for the actual id?

Comment: Yes , the first coloumn is index & second is actaul id. Please help..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file object is a line iterator, not a word iterator. So you need to change:

```
for i in f:
    url="http://graph.facebook.com/"+str(int(i))+"?fields=likes"
```

To:

```
for i in f:
    # i holds the line, not the index
    index, page_id = i.strip().split()[:2]
    url="http://graph.facebook.com/"+page_id+"?fields=likes"
    # ...
```

This way you split the line, after removing the line break (`'\n'`), to the `index` and the `page_id`, separately.

There is no need to cast the `page_id` string to an integer and back to string.

Comment: Error: Need more than 1 value to unpack  !!

Comment: I've fixed it, but make sure your file is the right format.